# Difference between indignation and umbrage

Tags: differences

Indignation

> anger, because of something that is wrong or not fair

Umbrage

> a feeling of being upset or annoyed, usually because you feel that 
>   someone has been rude or shown no respect to you

Definitions from Cambridge dictionary.

The distinction between them seems to be that umbrage can be used when something actually offensive or unjust is done to arouse anger, while indignation would be used only when there is a **perception** of injustice.

I want to know if the two words have the same connotation.

Comment: They both can be used regardless of whether the offense was real or merely perceived. The words are roughly synonymous, but 'indignation' is (in my idiolect) a stronger emotion; it's *anger* at an *injustice*. 'Umbrage' is weaker; it's *annoyance* at a (potentially small) offense.

Comment: Consider a scenario wherein I am in an interview. I do not like certain topics and have skipped them. The interviewer asks me too many  questions around those topics and rejects me for the same. Now I feel angry that I was rejected for what I was not prepared. This is no injustice, but mere bad luck. So should this anger be called indignation or umbrage?

Answer (score 1):

I think that indignation could apply to things done to **you or other people**, whereas umbrage is a kind of indignation which is limited to things done to you.

For example, you might feel indignant if you saw someone being very rude to an old person in the street, but you wouldn't feel umbrage.   If they were rude to you, you could feel either.